# Jquery 1.3.2 Ajax how to get response

Tags: jquery

Hi below is the code, i am calling GetAjaxComments function which sends ajax request and successfull completed but i am not getting any values in response (eg:server side function returned DbComment ="comment already exist"). Please help.

```
    function GetAjaxComments(sEmployeeCompensationID, iInfoType) {

$(document).ready(function() {
    var json = "{'EMPLOYEECOMPENSATION_ID':'" + sEmployeeCompensationID
        + "','iInfoType':'" + iInfoType
        + "'}";
        var ajaxPage = "AjaxGridRowSave.aspx?SaveRow=2"; //this page is where data is to be processed
        var options = {
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxPage,
        data: json,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        complete: function(data) {
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            if (msg.statusText != "OK") {
                OpenInfoPopup("Alert", "Error occured while retriving data.");
            }
        }
    };

});
var returnText = data;

 if (returnText != '') {

     var dbValues = new Array();
     dbValues = eval('(' + returnText + ')');

     if ((dbValues1.DbComment) && (dbValues1.DbComment != null) && (dbValues1.DbComment != '')) {
         switch (dbValues1.iInfoType) {
             case 1: OpenInfoPopup('Eligibility Override Reason', dbValues1.DbComment); break;
             case 2: OpenInfoPopup('Eligibility Override Rejection Reason', dbValues1.DbComment); break;
             case 3: OpenInfoPopup('Rejection Reason', dbValues1.DbComment); break;
             case 4: OpenInfoPopup('Guideline Override Reason', dbValues1.DbComment); break;
             case 5: OpenInfoPopup('Guideline Override rejection Reason', dbValues1.DbComment); break;
             case 6: OpenInfoPopup('Pay Range Override Reason', dbValues1.DbComment); break;
             case 7: OpenInfoPopup('Pay Range Override Rejection Reason', dbValues1.DbComment); break;
         }
     }


 }
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that jQuery doesn't set the content-type in the HttpRequestheader properly.

Add the following:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr){
     xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
},
```

To the Ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

Your code makes **no** sense what-so-ever.

Your code does not initate an AJAX request. You need to call one of [jQuery's AJAX functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to start an AJAX request using jQuery. Containing `$(document).ready()` like this makes **no** sense and will not be doing what you're expecting it to do.

`$(document).ready()` attaches a handler which is executed on page load. As the page load will almost certainly have happened when this function is executed, the provided function will be executed immediately, and will allocate a few local variables (all of which will be unavailable outside the scope of the function.

What you most probably want is:

```
function GetAjaxComments(sEmployeeCompensationID, iInfoType) {
    var json = "{'EMPLOYEECOMPENSATION_ID':'" + sEmployeeCompensationID + "','iInfoType':'" + iInfoType + "'}";
    var ajaxPage = "AjaxGridRowSave.aspx?SaveRow=2"; //this page is where data is to be processed;
    var returnText = '';

    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxPage,
            data: json,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                returnText = response;
            },
            error: function(msg) {
                if (msg.statusText != "OK") {
                    OpenInfoPopup("Alert", "Error occured while retriving data.");
                }
            }
        };

    });

    if (returnText != '') {
        var dbValues = new Array();
        dbValues = eval('(' + returnText + ')');

        if ((dbValues1.DbComment) && (dbValues1.DbComment != null) && (dbValues1.DbComment != '')) {
            switch (dbValues1.iInfoType) {
            case 1:
                OpenInfoPopup('Eligibility Override Reason', dbValues1.DbComment);
                break;
            case 2:
                OpenInfoPopup('Eligibility Override Rejection Reason', dbValues1.DbComment);
                break;
            case 3:
                OpenInfoPopup('Rejection Reason', dbValues1.DbComment);
                break;
            case 4:
                OpenInfoPopup('Guideline Override Reason', dbValues1.DbComment);
                break;
            case 5:
                OpenInfoPopup('Guideline Override rejection Reason', dbValues1.DbComment);
                break;
            case 6:
                OpenInfoPopup('Pay Range Override Reason', dbValues1.DbComment);
                break;
            case 7:
                OpenInfoPopup('Pay Range Override Rejection Reason', dbValues1.DbComment);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should read up on jQuery's [ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)

Using synchronous AJAX requests is extremely bad practise; the browser will be locked and unusable for the duration of the request. You should seriously consider handling the response using a callback. I've outlined how this works in [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956261/got-stuck-in-the-asynchronous-nature-of-ajax-requests/2956302#2956302), but in your example you can change your code to:

```
function GetAjaxComments(sEmployeeCompensationID, iInfoType) {
    var json = "{'EMPLOYEECOMPENSATION_ID':'" + sEmployeeCompensationID + "','iInfoType':'" + iInfoType + "'}";
    var ajaxPage = "AjaxGridRowSave.aspx?SaveRow=2"; //this page is where data is to be processed;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxPage,
        data: json,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(returnText) {

            if (returnText != '') {
                var dbValues = new Array();
                dbValues = eval('(' + returnText + ')');

                if ((dbValues1.DbComment) && (dbValues1.DbComment != null) && (dbValues1.DbComment != '')) {
                    switch (dbValues1.iInfoType) {
                    case 1:
                        OpenInfoPopup('Eligibility Override Reason', dbValues1.DbComment);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        OpenInfoPopup('Eligibility Override Rejection Reason', dbValues1.DbComment);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        OpenInfoPopup('Rejection Reason', dbValues1.DbComment);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        OpenInfoPopup('Guideline Override Reason', dbValues1.DbComment);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        OpenInfoPopup('Guideline Override rejection Reason', dbValues1.DbComment);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        OpenInfoPopup('Pay Range Override Reason', dbValues1.DbComment);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        OpenInfoPopup('Pay Range Override Rejection Reason', dbValues1.DbComment);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            if (msg.statusText != "OK") {
                OpenInfoPopup("Alert", "Error occured while retriving data.");
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: @vmisra: Try `alert()`ing the response you get (before you `eval()` it) to ensure it's the response you expect. Step through your code seeing where it reaches and doesn't reach. Post a link to the live version so someone can help you, if possible.