# how not to hard-code codeigniter link in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

i wrote the routine below to retrieve city based on selected country for my codeigniter application.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select#cbo_country").change(function() {
        $.post("http://localhost/main/index.php/city/get_data_by_country", {
            int_country_id  : $(this).val()
        },
        function(data) {
            // some code here
        },'json');
    })
});
```

as you can see, i hard-coded the url (http://localhost/main/index.php/city/get_data_by_country) and i know it's a bad practice but i can't help it.

is there a nice clean way to not hard-code the url? i used to use codeigniter's base_url(), but since i move the routine to a js file, i am no longer able to use the function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Taken (mostly) from my answer on [How to get relative path in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310620/how-to-get-relative-path-in-javascript/6310991#6310991).**

You've got two options:

1. Build a configuration/ preferences object in JavaScript which contains all your environment specific settings:

   ```
    var config = {
        base: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>",
        someOtherPref: 4
    };
   ```

   and then prefix the AJAX url with `config.base`.

   You have to place the config object in a place which is parsed by PHP; the standard choice is inside the `<head>` HTML element. Don't worry its a small config object, whose contents can change on each page, so it's perfectly warrented to stick it in there.
2. Use the [`<base />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/base) HTML tag to set the URL prefix for all relative URL's. This affects **all** relative URL's: image's, links etc.

Personally, I'd go for option 1. You'll most likely find that config object coming in handy elsewhere.

Comment: i forgot to comeback and pick your answer. i went for option 2 since i don't think base_url() will work on .js file. thanks.

Comment: option 1 is better, it's not a js file it's a PHP file.

Answer (score 2):

Change `"http://localhost/main/index.php/city/get_data_by_country"` to `"/main/index.php/city/get_data_by_country"` and it will work no matter what your base url is.

This works because the `/` before `main/index.php` says "start at the root and go the the `index.php` file in the `main` folder".

This is unless your document root folder is set to the `main` folder, if so, take out the `main`

Comment: Won't `/index.php` link to `http://localhost/index.php`, not `http://localhost/main/index.php`?

Comment: Yes it will, missed the main folder part. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is add a `data-baseurl` attribute to an element on the page (the `body` element works).  Then you can grab that from the JavaScript file.

```
<body data-baseurl="<?=base_url()?>">
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
$("select#cbo_country").change(function() {
    var baseURL = $('body').data('baseurl')
    $.post(baseURL+"city/get_data_by_country", {
        int_country_id  : $(this).val()
    },
    function(data) {
        // some code here
    },'json');
})
```