# All POST MVC Requests give 404 error

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

I have an MVC App which is giving a 404 errors when i use POST requests.

Here's the pertinent bits of code:

I have a WebAPI controller(although this also happens with "pure" MVC controllers) with a single method in it:

```
public class GetSomeDataController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string GetNumbers([FromBody]string value)
    {
        // Get 10 randomised numbers

        return //The numbers as JSON;
    }
}
```

In the JavaScript i have an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Api/GetSomeData/GetNumbers/",
    data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false, // Pass the data in the body of the request rather than in the URI.
})
.done(function (ajaxResult) {
    // handle the results
})
.fail(function (e) {
    // Handle errors
});
```

When i debug it from within VS 2013 i get my 10 numbers back no problem at all. However when i run the exact same code in IIS 8.5...
[image]

The page itself is an MVC routed page so routing is working on the server, but it does not Work when I call a controller action from a POST.

The error page reports that the StaticFile handler appears to be trying to handle the request - which of course fails.
[image]

I am going out of my head trying to figure out what is going on. Does anyone have any ideas?

These are the things i can remember trying:

Adding various things to web.config (No Discernible effect):

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
            type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule,
            System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0,
            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```

,

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

- I am definitely running in Integrated mode
- The application pool is running under an account with access to the folder
- The application pool is running in .NET 4.0
- Disabling and re-enabling ASP.NET 4.5 in Windows features and settings
- aspnet_regiis - i (not supported for IIS 8.5)
- Tracing the request: (No new information)
  [image]
- Changing the ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 request path to "*"
- Changing the ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 verbs (POST is already included in the list)

Comment: try this way: `url: "/Api/GetSomeData"`

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work either debugging in VS or running from IIS - mind you i wouldn't expect it to as the WebAPI route i have registered requires an action as well as a controller: `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"`

Comment: check this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Thanks - i am configuring and using my routing according to a combination of the sections entitled HTTP Methods and Routing by action name. As i said in my post this is not a routing problem - routing would have shown up debugging in IIS Express - this is an IIS configuration issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turns put to be nothing to do with IIS or routing.

When debugging in Local IIS or running the site from IIS i was running the application as a sub application - i.e. the address to my application wan't `http://localhost/` it was `Http://localhost/WebScratchPad/`.

The AJAX request was aimiing at `Http://localhost/Api/GetSomeData/GetNumbers/` because of this line in the $.ajax request:

`url: "/Api/GetSomeData/GetNumbers/",`

They should have gone to `Http://localhost/WebScratchPad/Api/GetSomeData/GetNumbers/`

by doing this:

`url: "/WebScratchPad/Api/GetSomeData/GetNumbers/",`

So much for poking around in the Web.config!

Of course this isn't the entire solution as idealy that would be dynamic - my application shouldn't have to be installed on a sub application of some website served by IIS - so i will pass a prefix in from the configuration or similar to allow the "/WebScratchPad/" portion to be a little dynamic as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310620/how-to-get-relative-path-in-javascript/6310991#6310991).